# If I log out, and log back in. the bottom tab navigator does not appear

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

The routing starts at the main().I dont think the mistake is here.
The first page is CredentialPage() because its set to home

In CredentialPage(), I check if the user is logged in, if he is. I send him to NavigatorView(). The issue could be here maybe.
Once the CredentialPage loads, the user is routed to AllJobsView()

here is a small video of the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkBueUr_gN0

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Vendor Management',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const CredentialPage(),  // <======= 
      routes: {
        loginRoute: (context) => const LoginView(),
        registerRoute: (context) => const RegisterView(),
        verifyEmailRoute: (context) => const VerifyEmailView(),
        //
        allJobsRoute: ((context) => const AllJobsView()),
        myJobsRoute: (context) => const MyJobsView(),
        newJobRoute: (context) => const CreateUpdateJobView(),
        myJobApplicationsRoute: (context) => const JobApplicationView(),

        navigatorViewRoute: (context) => const NavigatorView(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

```
class CredentialPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CredentialPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: AuthService.firebase().initialize(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:
            final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
            if (user != null) {
              if (user.isEmailVerified) {
                return const NavigatorView();  // <============
              } else {
                return const VerifyEmailView();
              }
            } else {
              return const LoginView();
            }
          default:
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Once the CredentialPage loads, the user is routed to AllJobsView()

```
class _NavigatorViewState extends State<NavigatorView> {
  late final FirebaseCloudStorage _jobsService;
  String get userId => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.id;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _jobsService = FirebaseCloudStorage();
    super.initState();
  }

  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    AllJobsView(),                    <========
    MyJobsView(),
    CreateUpdateJobView(),
    JobApplicationsView(),
    Center(
      child: Text('Profile'),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(          <=== bottom nav
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 10,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
            label: 'Open jobs',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'My jobs',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Create Job',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Job Applications',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was with the nagivation route when i clicked logg in.

instead of sending me to the all jobs, i changed it to navigator view!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).